# Insert data on comment post

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

I am trying to find reference for comment_post to insert custom data to custom table when comment post.

I want to insert below things to my custom table

1. Comment's Post ID
2. Custom content (which will done with custom query)

Can anyone please help me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're after but this is how you would get the content of a newly posted comment

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'my_comment_callback' );
function my_comment_callback($id) {
    $comment = get_comments(array(
        'ID' => $id
    ));

    // $content is the actual text the user posted
    $content = $comment->comment_content;
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Please see my comment in `s_ha_dum` answer. Thank you very much for your instant help.

Comment: @pixelngrain ... If you used `comment_post` you should select this as the solution.

Comment: which as the solution? your answer or my answer? Confused to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I think you are looking for the [`wp_insert_comment` hook](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/comment.php#L1293) or one of the [comment transitions hooks](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/comment.php#L1213). Your question doesn't allow for a more detailed answer. There just isn't enough information.

```
function insert_comment_extra_wpse_85096($cid) {
  // $cid is your comment ID
}
add_action('wp_insert_comment','insert_comment_extra_wpse_85096');
```

See Also: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_transition_comment_status

Comment: I am really sorry for confusion and thanks a lot for your reply. However I wanted to add some custom data into the custom table when new comment post. I have done it using comment_post action hook. Adding as an answer. Thank you very much for your instant help.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using comment_post action hook. Here is the answer if anyone need in future.

```
add_action('comment_post', 'insert_gallery');
function insert_gallery() {

    global $wpdb, $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    $wpdb->insert(
        $wpdb->prefix. 'my_medias',
        array(
            'post_id' => $post_id,
            'image_name' => 'trial-image1',
            'status' => 1
        ),

        array(
            '%d',
            '%s',
            '%d'
        )

    );    

}
```