# Get Comment Author ID on the fly while posting

Tags: comments, author

I am adding custom data to custom table while author posting a comment. Please find my code in my own answer here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85109/9821

```
add_action('comment_post', 'insert_gallery');
function insert_gallery() {

    global $wpdb, $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    $wpdb->insert(
        $wpdb->prefix. 'my_medias',
        array(
            'post_id' => $post_id,
            'image_name' => 'trial-image1',
            'status' => 1
        ),            
        array(
            '%d',
            '%s',
            '%d'
        )            
    );            
}
```

Now I want to add one more column of 'author_ID' and not able to get the comment author id on the fly.

Can anyone help me to get comment author id on the fly and insert into custom table column `author_ID`

Answer (score 1):

Ah! It was so simple :P

Just using WP built in function

```
get_current_user_id( )
```

and all done. Thanks a lot.